# Empty response body with ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, tornado

I'm posting a username and password to a tornado server. If the credentials are valid, it returns a cookie and a simple "OK" text response.

This works with an ordinary web client, but when I try to do it with ajax, the response body is empty. Chrome cancels the request before it completes for some reason, and firefox highlights it in red even though it receives a 200 status. I'm trying to work out what's happening.

I've set up CORS headers, and I can see the OPTIONS request is returning valid data (chrome doesn't complain about it).

Here's my tornado server:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseMixin, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def options(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return CORS headers
        """
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept, authorization')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age', 21600)
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Validates the user's ID and token
        """
        try:
            # ... perform checks - all OK, so then:
            self.set_secure_cookie(
                    "auth", urllib.urlencode({'user_id': self.user_id,
                                              'token': user['token']}))
            self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            self.finish("OK")
            return
```

The content length is correctly set, but for some reason neither firefox or chrome display the response body.

I'm assuming this is CORS related somehow since my behavioural tests which hit this endpoint all pass (and they assert that the response body contains "OK").

I'm issuing the request (using angularjs) as follows:

```
postData = new Array('user_id=' + id, 'token=' + token);

$http.post(url, postData.join('&'), {headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
   .success(authSuccessHandler)
   .error(authErrorHandler);
```

In chrome it immediately enters the error callback and the request is marked as 'pending' then 'canceled' in the network tab of the dev tools.

Has anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it reaching the `post` function when you try it through the browser?

Comment: Yes, the ajax request successfully logs the user in, but FF & Chrome don't consider the response valid. Chrome aborts after sending it for some reason. I need them to accept the cookie that is returned.

Comment: Could you share your client-side code with us?

Comment: What's the value of url?

Comment: Also in Postman the response is correctly displayed and no errors. The source URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/, destination is http://127.0.0.1:8888/login

Comment: Try maybe prefixing "http://"...?

Comment: SO has stripped it off. It does have the protocol.

Comment: Can't think of what else... I would try to sniff the traffic with wireshark (you'd have to run the browser on a different computer) and maybe see what exactly happens to the TCP stream.

Comment: I'll try putting it on a different domain to make sure they aren't clashing somehow. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the CORS headers were only on the OPTIONS endpoint, not on POST. I added them to POST as well and now it all works.